# how to compare list to text file and delete missing entries

Tags: python, list, text-files

If I have a list with different values like `Eind, Shf, Asuf`.
And a text file with

```
20:36:00 - Baarn
20:36:00 - Enschede
20:37:00 - Eindhoven
20:37:00 - Eind
20:37:00 - Shf
20:37:00 - Asuf
20:38:00 - Nijmegen
```

How do I delete the values in the list from the text file but delete the whole line.

Comment: What code have you tried? What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Please better define what you are asking, and suppy some code that you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new file:

Given that you have a list like this

```
to_delete = ['Eind', 'Shf', 'Asuf']
```

you can open both your current file and a new file and create a new version

```
in_file = open('input.txt')
out_file = open('output.txt')
for line in in_file:
     last_word = line.split(' ')[-1]
     if not last_word in to_delete:
          out_file.write(line)
in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

in this way, the new file has only the entries that don't match with the itemes in your list. In the code above I assume that your file has to check only the last word with whatever is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is your list:

```
deletion_list = ["Eind", "Shf", "Asuf"]
```

First convert into a set in order to make faster searches:

```
deletion_set = set(deletion_list)
```

Then filter it out:

```
# Open the file in a with statement to make sure it closes correctly
with open("input.txt") as input_file, open("output.txt", "w") as output_file:
    # Write to new file
    list(map(output_file.write,
             # Iterates over all lines in file and take those in set
             (line for line in input_file
              # Checks if line is in set
              if line.rpartition(" ")[-1] in deletion_set))
```

This is probably the best way. It's efficient and bug-less (with statements prevent unknown exceptions from keeping files open)